# Are all subspaces also nullspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I know that all nullspaces are subspaces. Is the converse true? That is, are all subspaces also nullspaces? In other words, are the sets equivalent?

Comment: You can always create a linear transformation $T$ such that $\text{Ker}(T)=S$, where $S$ is your subspace and then extend the basis of $S$ to the whole space to define $T$ completely.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You could make any subspace a null space by mapping it to the zero vector

Comment: I don't know what  Ker() mean. I am very new to all of this. But based on the answer I am guessing nullspace is a proper subset of subspace? Might you breakdown the explanation for a newbie to understand?

Comment: Take a basis of the subspace, complete it a basis of the entire space. Specify a linear mapping by mapping the basis vectors of the subspace to zero and the others to a linearly independent set. Alternatively, consider the projection onto the quotient of the ambient space by the subspace.

Comment: It is true that for every subspace $S$ of $\Bbb R^n$, there exists an $m \times n$ matrix whose nullspace is $S$.  Saying that "the sets are equivalent" seems like a strange way to phrase it though

Comment: $\text{Ker}(T)=\{x \in V \, | \, T(x)=0\}$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom do you mean "there exists an mxn matrix?"

Comment: @Mwen whoops! Yes I do, just fixed that

Comment: if I may ask it differently for clarification (apologies if I'm slow to getting this): Does there exist a context where a subspace is **not** a nullspace?

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: Let $S=\text{span}(\{u,v\}) \subseteq \Bbb{R}^3$ ($u,v$ are linearly independent). Then $S$ is a subspace. Now we construct $T: \Bbb{R}^3 \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}^3$ such that $T(u)=T(v)=0$. Now pick a vector which is not in $S$, call it $w$. Define $T(w)=w$ (say) and now you have a linear transformation with $S$ as the null space.

Comment: Saying "a subspace is a nullspace" is weird because the term "nullspace" is contextual. That is, we tend not to talk about something being "a nullspace"; we instead say that a subspace is "the nullspace of the matrix $M$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, it sounds like you are learning linear algebra in terms of matrices without discussing linear transformations in detail.  So, I will stick to the matrix setting.

It is true that for every subspace $S$ of $\Bbb R^n$, there exists an $m \times n$ matrix whose nullspace is $S$. If we have a basis $v_1,\dots,v_k$ for our subspace $S$, then we can produce a matrix whose nullspace is $S$ as follows:

Let $A$ denote the matrix whose columns are $v_1,\dots,v_d$.  First, find a basis for the nullspace of $A^T$; we will refer to this nullspace as $N$.  Because the row-space of $A^T$ is $S$, $N = S^\perp$ (that is, $N$ is the "orthogonal complement" of $S$).

Let $w_1,\dots,w_k$ denote the basis that we found for $N$.  Let $B$ denote the matrix whose columns are $w_1,\dots,w_k$.  The row-space of $B^T$ is $N$; it follows that the null-space of $B^T$ is $N^\perp$, the orthogonal complement of $N$.  That is,
$$
\operatorname{null}(B^T) = N^\perp = (S^\perp)^\perp = S.
$$
So, $B$ is a matrix whose null-space is $S$.

Comment: Thanks to all the commenters as well. Yeah, it's a fascinating subject that I am picking up on my own and so there are challenges.